# CLion не может найти функцию

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

Если в CLion 2016.3.2 начать новый проект и изменить файл main.cpp таким образом:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int a=0,b=1;
    std::swap(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

То IDE сообщит об ошибке: о том, что не может найти функцию `std::swap` с правильной сигнатурой, при этом предлагая варианты из `stl_bvector.h`, например, `inline void swap(_Bit_reference __x, _Bit_reference __y) noexcept`. Код при этом, очевидно, компилируется нормально. Если убрать вторую строку, то ошибки не будет.

Как-либо «подавить» эту ошибку тоже не получается, Alt+Enter на строке с ошибкой не работает.

Как всё-таки избавиться от этой ошибки?

Comment: `#include <algorithm>` забыли

Comment: @Sublihim здесь написано, что с c++11 эта функция в `<utility>` http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap В любом случае, ошибка остаётся.

Comment: добавил метку C++11. Можно попробовать уточнить: `std::swap<int,int>(a,b)` А какой компилятор в CLion?

Comment: @Sublihim, спасибо, так ошибки нет. Только там просто `<int>`. Напишите ответ, я его приму. CLion использует системный компилятор, а для анализа ошибок, видимо, свой парсер.

Comment: Да, видимо ошибка CLion. Можно попробовать зарепортить им баг :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать уточнить:

```
std::swap<int>(a,b)
```

Но, если и без уточнения шаблона все компилировалось нормально, может это ошибка самой IDE?

Comment: Ещё обнаружил, что если дополнительно добавить `#include <tuple>` то и на этот вариант будет выдавать ошибку. Но так вроде работает: `std::swap<int>((int&)a,(int&)b);`

Comment: @Imieee точно надо репортить в жетбрайнс

Comment: уже, по-моему, есть: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8423

Comment: точно. Ну, теперь ждать, пока исправят )