# Неопределённая ссылка на "ceil" CLion

Tags: c, типы, clion

Есть следующая строка:

```c
#include <math.h>

//...

int stepSize = ceil((*stepNumber + 1) / 2);
```

где `stepNumber` имеет тип `int*`.

Чтобы избавиться от приведения к `int` при делении и, как следствие, округления в меньшую сторону, добавил приведение к `double`:

```c
int stepSize = ceil(((double)*stepNumber + 1) / 2);
```

И вот тут началось странное: перманентная ошибка **неопределённая ссылка на «ceil»** в каких-бы то ни было вариациях приведения аргумента к `double`. При том, что при наведении на функцию IDE подсказывает, что она принимает именно `double`.

P.S. **Не является дубликатом [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620876/clion-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E), т.к. там рассматривалась шаблонная функция и решение зависело от аргумента шаблона!**

Вопрос: чем обоснована описанная ошибка и, самое главное, как от неё избавиться?

Comment: Это же сообщение от линкера, при чем тут clion? А платформа случаем не linux?

Comment: @user7860670 Платформа Linux. Я понимаю, что сообщение от линкера, просто в других IDE подобного не встречал.

Comment: Наверное надо прилинковать библиотеку `m`, аналогично для использования мьютексов и потоков надо линковать `pthread`

Comment: @user7860670 Подскажите тогда, как это сделать. И кстати, почему тогда без преобразования к `double` всё работает без ручной линковки библиотек?

Comment: У вас в CLion должен быть CMakeLists.txt, там для своей цели (`target`) пишете `target_link_library(target m)`.

Comment: @eanmos либо  я чего-то не понимаю, либо Вы что-то не то написали. Пишет что такой команды нет. И что такое `m` в данном случае? Не понятно. Допустим цель называется main. Напишите, какую именно строку необходимо добавить в CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @V-Mor, да, должно быть librar**ies**: `target_link_libraries(main m)`. `m` — это от `math`.